# Mouse pointer not captured in virtual box

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, mouse

I've installed **android x86** into my **windows 7 OS** via **virtual box**. Though I can see a small window saying *"The Virtual Machine reports that the guest OS supports **mouse pointer integration**. This means that you do not need to capture the mouse pointer . . ."*, I can't see the mouse pointer within the virtual box window whenever I move the mouse over it. What has went wrong? Is the mouse pointer playing an invisible game with me? Or, Is it not captured at all? Help me see the mouse pointer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to Just disable "Mouse integration" in Machine tab: http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/issues/detail?id=341

Or by right-clicking the mouse icon in the bottom right corner of your VM window and picking Disable Mouse Integration

Comment: There is no "Mouse integration" option in Machine tab in latest versions of VB.

Comment: @Dims you can always do it by right-clicking the mouse icon in the bottom right corner of your VM window and picking `Disable Mouse Integration`

Answer (score 0):

I am running a Windows 7 box with VB running an insider view of Windows 10 and I was getting the same message, what I needed to do was go into settings>system and under pointing device change it from ps2 mouse to usb tablet and I was able to work in and out of the VM without holding down the home key. took a bit of digging, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Answer as of 2017 and Virtual Box 5.x. And assuming that magic HostKey ist still the RightCtrl key (otherwise change accordingly)

In case your status bar is hidden:

**1. If in full-screen-mode: <kbd>RightCtrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to leave.**

**2. If no bottom status bar: <kbd>RightCtrl</kbd>-<kbd>Pos1</kbd> to show.**

[image]

**3. You can check the mouse status at the bottom right:**

Blue Mouse with green arrow is, what you will usually want. (One consistent pointer across host&guest, which in most cases requires virtual guest additions installed). (Btw: I could only check, not change mouse status there...)

[image]